# Folder creation with custom folder content type

Tags: content-type

I have my own folder content type inherited from base Folder content type. I am trying to create folders based on my own content type programmatically without success. I change newFolder.Item["ContentTypeId"] to my content type id but nothing seems to be changed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That should work.  You may be missing the .Update() call after setting your content type id (http://asadewa.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/adding-a-custom-content-type-specific-item-on-a-sharepoint-list/).  Whenever something like this isn't working for me, it's usually because I forgot that.